# Using session variable to use info on different pages

Tags: php, session

i'm having a bit of a problem. I'm trying to set up a simple webpage with only three .php pages. I want a session variable $_SESSION['userID'] to be set when a user is logged in and I want the index page to show extra info if someone is logged in.

On index.php I want to show some info, if a user is logged in I want to show some extra info.
login.php - simple log in form.
login_exe.php - takes care of database connection and verification.

So this was my idea:

On index.php, check if session is started, if not: start.

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
  echo "session started";
}
```

later on, check if $_SESSION['userID'] contains a value, if so: print a string

```
if($_SESSION['userID'] != null){
   echo "User logged in";
}
```

On login_exe.php i've almost the same code:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
    echo "session started";
}
```

in verification function:

```
$_SESSION['userID'] = $data['userID'];
header("Location: index.php");
```

The problem is that a new session is started on every page. How can I fix this and only start the session once? Thanks in advance

Comment: first of all, put `session_start();` call on top. Always.

Comment: `session_start()` should always be on top of the document. Instead of checking the whole `$_SESSION` check for `$_SESSION['key']`.

Comment: Should I remove "if (!isset($_SESSION)) {" clause and just have the session_start()? And do I need to have the session_start() on both index and login_exe.php? @vlzvl

Comment: You should just put `session_start();` on top of documents that using sessions. If you have 5 .php files that using sessions, then put 5 times the `session_start()` on top of them. This is because `session_start()` sends **headers**. Then, you should use something like `isset($_SESSION["foo"])` and not just the entire `$_SESSION` array, where `foo` is something you set previously.

Comment: @vlzvl You should put that as an answer, that helped me a lot!

Comment: i put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just put `session_start()` on top of documents that *using sessions*. Say, if you have 5 .php files that using sessions, then put 5 times the `session_start()` on top of them.

This is because `session_start()` sends headers and headers must be sent before any output (for example, any **echo** or **whitespace**).

Then, you should use something like `isset($_SESSION["foo"])` and not just the entire **$_SESSION** array, where `foo` is something you set previously.

If you dont want sessions at all or need to reset the entire array, just call `session_destroy()` which effectively destroy the current session. Use `unset($_SESSION["foo"])` when you want to get rid of a key.

Finally, you might get *weird cases* where you cannot read session key you write at. In these cases check what is the path of sessions and if they're writeable, or change their path:

```
$path = session_save_path();        // what is the path

is_writable($path);                 // can i write to it?

session_save_path("my/new/path");   // change the darn path; 
                                    // put -even- before session_start()!
```

:)
glad i help

Answer (score 0):

I think the PHP manuals are really good compared to ...ahm, so just read about session_start(). It says:

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one (...)

so all you need is session_start() very early in your code. This must be executed on every request (maybe as include).

Your code checking the userId looks fine, one important hint here: you should know exactly what isset(), empty() and the like mean in PHP, so always have the [comparision of comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should not ask new answers (edit: questions) in comments. Be as systematic here as you are in coding.

**How to end a session:**

This gives room for discussion, because there is the session cookie, which is client side, and the session data, which is server side.

I recommend:

```
$_SESSION = null;
```

Reason: this will clear all login and other associated data immediately. It leaves the cookie intact, which is normally of no concern, since all associated data is gone.

Comment: Thank you, although I removed the comment before you answered. But still, thank you!

Comment: you should also not posting 2 answers as a user